# tailing log file not registering events (logstash forwarder with -tail=true)

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder, logstash-configuration

I want to forward only newly created logs to **logstash server** from **logstash-forwarder**
I have a **logstash-forwarder.conf** file

```
{

  "network": {
    "servers": [ "X.X.X.X:5001" ],
    "ssl certificate": "/etc/ssl/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt",
    "ssl key": "/etc/ssl/private/logstash-forwarder.key",
    "ssl ca": "/etc/ssl/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt",
    "timeout": 300
 },

  # The list of files configurations
  "files": [
                {
                    "paths": [ "/home/user/Programs/zookeeperlog.log" ],
                    "fields": { "logtype": "zookeeper-log", "type": "logs"  }
                },
                {
                    "paths": [ "/var/log/syslog" ],
                    "fields": { "logtype": "kafka-log", "type": "logs"  }
                },
                {
                    "paths": [ "/var/log/syslog" ],
                    "fields": { "logtype": "storm-log", "type": "logs"  }
                }

    ]
}
```

I wanted to know if there is a option something like "start_position => end" to add to this configuration file.
I also tried using -tail=true while running logstash-forwarder. It takes snapshots but harvest doesn't seem to registrar events. It registers events only without -tail command line option or when -tail=false is given, which forwards all logs from beginning.